# Excel 2010: Can I hide columns without excluding the data from a graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

In Excel 2010, is it possible to hide columns but still have the values show up in a graph?

I have a graph of monthly data going back to 2005, with each month's data in a column. If I hide the columns, say, for everything before 2010, then the graph only shows the 2010 data.

Is it possible to hide the columns, but still have the data in the graph?

Answer (score 26):

**Solution**

- Open the workbook and click a chart whose hidden data and empty cells you want to display.
- Click Design > Edit Data Source > Hidden and Empty Cells.
- Select 'Show data in hidden rows and columns'.
- From 'Show empty cells as', select an appropriate option then click OK.

**Details**

By default in Excel, the hidden data in rows and columns is not displayed in a chart. Empty cells are displayed as gaps. Excel allows you to display the hidden data and change the way the empty cells are displayed. Rather than displaying the empty cells as gaps, you can display them as zero values or you can span the gaps with a line.

Comment: Why did someone down vote this? It is the right answer.

Comment: Not working in Excel 2016, The button is grayed out when sourcing data from a Pivot table using a tabular layout format.