# Keep values for grouped or hidden cells in graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel 2010: Can I hide columns without excluding the data from a graph?](https://superuser.com/questions/207845/excel-2010-can-i-hide-columns-without-excluding-the-data-from-a-graph)

I have a graph based on data contained in cell columns that can be grouped. Whenever I collapse the group, in essence hiding the column, the values disappear from the graph.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Sorry, just found http://superuser.com/questions/207845/excel-2010-can-i-hide-columns-without-excluding-the-data-from-a-graph is a 100% dupe. Can someone close this please?

Comment: flagged as a dupe. regards Dave